# How to define a macro variable using equation with variables from dataset in SAS Miner

Tags: macros, sas, equation

I am trying to use `&let` in the beginning of my script to define a new macro variable... it should consist of equation from variables from dataset. The equation looks something like this, but SAS always gives me error like this (Runtime error was encountered, please see the log...).

The equation:

```
%let var_bad = (receivable_actual * 0.5) - 
               (EM_EVENTPROBABILITY * 0.02 * receivable_actual) + 
               ((1 - EM_EVENTPROBABILITY) * 0.5 * (receivable_actual - amt_instalment));
```

Can you guys help me fix it?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Please take a look into the log file for the actual error msg. You can either find it under Results->View->SASResults or if it is truncated look for the EMLOG.log/EMTRAIN.log file in the actual Nodes Folder

Comment: Hi, I already posted it as an answer here, because it was too long for the reply to your comment

Comment: Don't you get score code from EM that you can use?

Answer (score 0):

@Jetzler: These are the errors it shows me in log.

ERROR 214-322: Variable name ( is not valid.

ERROR 22-7: Invalid option name -.

ERROR 23-7: Invalid value for the KEEP option.

```
                         ---
                         23
```

1    !  (receivable_actual * 0.5) - (EM_EVENTPROBABILITY * 0.02 * receivable_actual) + ((1 - EM_EVENTPROBABILITY) * 0.5 * (receivable_actual - amt_instalment))
                           -                                                         -
                           214                                                       22
ERROR 214-322: Variable name * is not valid.

ERROR 22-7: Invalid option name +.

1    !  (receivable_actual * 0.5) - (EM_EVENTPROBABILITY * 0.02 * receivable_actual) + ((1 - EM_EVENTPROBABILITY) * 0.5 * (receivable_actual - amt_instalment))
                             ---                                                                                  -
                             214                                                                                  22
14338 +                                rename=(em_eventprobability = score_no_call));
                                       -------
                                       22    22
                                       201   76
ERROR 214-322: Variable name 0.5 is not valid.

ERROR 22-7: Invalid option name *.

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, (, -, :, ;, END, INDSNAME, KEY, KEYS, NOBS, OPEN, POINT, *DATA*, *LAST*, *NULL*.

ERROR 201-322: The option is not recognized and will be ignored.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just calculate the variable in the dataset and then select it into a macro variable?

Comment: Well because em_eventprobability is the prediction from my logistic regression model which is a essential part of the equation. Basically I have some data, I do statistics on them and after that I try to create some of my own monitoring nodes,

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to combine macro variables and variables from a dataset in your %let statement, which is your problem. Functions like %eval and %sysevalf could help if you were only combining macro variables.

Comment: Then how can I make it so I will be able to combine macro variables and variables at the same time?

Comment: The easiest way is to save your macro variables as variables in the dataset (include a line in the dataset similar to "var_in_dataset = &macro_var.;")